# How to resolve "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when searching depth-first in a 2d arraylist?

Tags: java, tree, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I'm programming an AI game in Java. I have an (2d) arraylist which represents the gridworld.
In the gridworld there are randomly placed objects. An object is represented by black squares (and you cannot walk over black squares).

I would like to find the shortest path to color all the squares. 
The class looks like this:

```
public class DepthFirstAI {
  private int nodeCounter = 0;

  // run this function for each move
  private Node<ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> buildTree(Node<ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> tree) {
        if(nodeCounter > 0) {
            leaves.clear();
            getLeaves(tree);

            for(Node<ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> child : leaves) {
                child.addChild(bla(child).getData()); // add new childs (based on the possible directions) to the node
            }
        } else {
            tree = bla(tree);
        }

        nodeCounter++;
        return tree;
    }

    public Node<ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> bla(Node<ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> node) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> grid = node.getData().getValue();

        int roboX = roomGUI.player.x; // x location of player
        int roboY = roomGUI.player.y; // y location of player


        // Add possible directions (top, left, right, bottom) to directionsList
        .......

            Directions[] directions = directionsList.toArray(new Directions[0]);
            for (Directions d : directions) { // Create new child for each possible direction with the new grid + the name of the direction
                switch (d) {
                    case TOP: {
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> tempGrid = grid;
                        // Color squares visited by player
                        .....

                        Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> child = new Pair<>(Directions.TOP, tempGrid);
                        node.addChild(child);
                        break;
                    }
                    case BOTTOM: {
                        ...
                        break;
                    }
                    case RIGHT: {
                        ...
                        break;
                    }
                    case LEFT: {
                        ...
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tree;
    }

public class Node<T> {
        private ArrayList<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        private Node<T> parent = null;
        private Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> data = null;

        public Node(Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node(Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> data, Node<T> parent) {
            this.data = data;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public ArrayList<Node<T>> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public boolean hasChildren() {
            return children.size() > 0;
        }

        public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void addChild(Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> data) {
            Node<T> child = new Node<T>(data);
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        public Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> getData() {
            return this.data;
        }

        public void setData(Pair<Directions, ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public boolean isRoot() {
            return (this.parent == null);
        }

        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return this.children.size() == 0;
        }

        public void removeParent() {
            this.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

While running the code there are so many leaves after the 10th move (about 1.000.000) that the application fails with the following exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I know what is going wrong and why (because there are probably too many items in the tree), but I don't know how to fix this.

How am I able to create a tree with all possible options to find the shortest path?

Comment: Please post [mre]. Include hard coded test data.

Comment: @c0der it is really difficult to make a reproducible example. The game is very large and has many different classes which are having their own responsibility.

Comment: The mre should show the problem. Not your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not looking at your code, but at the general problem, you want to look at using the idea of partial-expansion. (eg Partial-Expansion A* - PEA*) The idea is that you generate all successors at each move, but then throw them away to save memory and just keep the index of the current successor. (You could keep more than one to save time.) Then, when you want to explore the next child you regenerate the successors and continue.

This has the potential to fix memory issues when you have lots of successors. (Assuming your problems aren't actually caused by garbage collection or other bugs in your code.) But, note that your tree may too large to search efficiently even if you resolve the space issues. Many DFS problems grow exponentially with the depth of the tree, so try it on really small problems to make sure it is working first.